# Rundeck different output running scripts

Tags: bash, rundeck

Thanks for taking time to read this question.

I'm having issues running scripts into Rundeck. Having the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE=$(whereis -b service | awk '{ print $2 }')
MDBC="/etc/mongod.conf"
CHECK=$(ps axu | grep mongod | grep -v grep | wc -l)

if [ $CHECK -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Restarting MongoDB"
  $(which mongod) -f $MDBC 
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
    echo "Restart failed. Trigger this job manually."
  else 
    echo "Service restarted."; fi
else
  echo "Service is up and running!"; fi
```

Running locally in the server, gives the expected output:

```
sudo bash -x test.sh 
++ whereis -b service
++ awk '{ print $2 }'
+ SERVICE=/sbin/service
+ MDBC=/etc/mongod.conf
++ grep -v grep
++ wc -l
++ grep mongod
++ ps axu
+ CHECK=0
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'Restarting MongoDB'
Restarting MongoDB
++ which mongod
+ /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 84141
child process started successfully, parent exiting
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ echo 'Service restarted.'
Service restarted.
```

Running the same code as **script** option in Rundeck, produces the following:

```
++ awk '{ print $2 }'
++ whereis -b service
+ SERVICE=/sbin/service
+ MDBC=/etc/mongod.conf
++ grep -v grep
++ ps axu
++ wc -l
++ grep mongod
+ CHECK=3
+ '[' 3 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'Service is up and running!'
Service is up and running!
```

As you can see, in the first output, the result for variable `CHECK` is equal to **0**, since no MongoDB processes are running.

The second output is taking as **3** the value for `CHECK`, hence, the `if` condition exits immediately.

My Rundeck version is the open source version 3.3.5

Any advices?

Comment: On your script step, you defined "Invocation String" (as `/bin/bash`) and "File extension" (as `.sh`)? (both available clicking on the "Advanced" button).

Comment: Hi @MegaDrive68k thanks for your help! Yes, I've put those values and the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing your script it seems that the line `ps axu | grep mongodb | grep -v grep | wc -l` isn't the best way to verify if the process is up, for example, running the line alone works like a charm, but called from a rundeck script step,  another process (bash) with "mongodb" name is created and referenced like this (generating  two lines and always exiting):

```sh
user      112156  0.0  0.0   2596   752 pts/1    S+   18:09   0:00 sh myscript.sh
user      112166  0.1  0.2 754928 48196 pts/1    Sl+  18:09   0:00 /path/to/mongodb/binary
```

Maybe the best way to identify your service to restart it would be something like (of course you can improve it):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

service docker status | grep 'active (running)' > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "restarting docker"
    sudo service docker restart > /dev/null
    echo "docker restarted"
else
    echo "docker service is running"
fi
```

Looks like this on a Rundeck [job definition](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>927d0085-c4f8-45c9-ba2c-01575b167c76</id>
    <loglevel>DEBUG</loglevel>
    <name>RestartService</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[#!/bin/bash

service docker status | grep 'active (running)' > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "restarting docker"
    sudo service docker restart > /dev/null
    echo "docker restarted"
else
    echo "docker service is running"
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>927d0085-c4f8-45c9-ba2c-01575b167c76</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Better if you set the service as an option:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='service' value='docker' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>927d0085-c4f8-45c9-ba2c-01575b167c76</id>
    <loglevel>DEBUG</loglevel>
    <name>RestartService</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[#!/bin/bash

service @option.service@ status | grep 'active (running)' > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "restarting @option.service@"
    sudo service @option.service@ restart > /dev/null
    echo "@option.service@ restarted"
else
    echo "docker service is running"
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>927d0085-c4f8-45c9-ba2c-01575b167c76</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Both jobs tested and works, feel free to use or modify them.

Of course, to restart processes, you need `sudo` elevation and [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/sudo-local-execution) plugin would be useful if the service coexists with Rundeck at the same server (it's a [node executor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDnpR.jpg) / [file copier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI1V2.jpg)) or check [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#secondary-sudo-password-authentication) if it's about an external server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't this a bug from Rundeck? I mean, why Rundeck is creating another process with the name of mongodb? As my understanding, rundeck sends the script as ```script``` for name... I modified the line following your logic and worked, but is weird why Rundeck is not able to process the logic from the first example.

Comment: Not a bug, in fact, if you launch the script manually with the same name of the process this issue happens (and you will see two "MongoDB" strings at the moment of verifying the process), maybe rundeck internally do the same (the bash call containing the mongodb command and the mongodb command itself). I'm glad to know that's solved!